# Uniqueness of an order $3$ subgroup of $S_6$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

$S_6$ being the set of permutations on $6$ elements, I have to prove that there exists only one order $3$ subgroup of the group that it forms with composition.

Of course, the identity has to be part of the subgroup. In this case, let's say the subgroup is {$\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1$, $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2$, e}. The inverses of $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2$ have to be in the subgroup, which means that either $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1\circ\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2=\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2\circ\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1=e$, or $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1\circ\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1=\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2\circ\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2=e$

For the second option, $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1\circ\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2 ,\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2\circ\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1$ will also have to be a part of the subgroup. Them being equal to $e$ woudn't work since we already set inverses for them both.

I don't know how to proceed from here. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The second option cannot happen in a subgroup of order $3$, since it would imply having elements of order $2$.

Comment: If your text is using the chemistry notation, $S_6$ is $S_3$ (because it's a group of order $6$). But otherwise this is a horrible typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a group has order $3$ then, by Lagrange's theorem, the order of each of its elements is either $1$ or $3$. Of course, the only element whose order is $1$ is the identity. So, a group of order $3$ has one element whose order is $1$ and two elements whose order is $3$. But $S_3$ has exactly two elements whose order is $3$: $(1\ \ 2\ \ 3)$ and $(1\ \ 3\ \ 2)$. Since$$\bigl\{\operatorname{id},(1\ \ 2\ \ 3),(1\ \ 3\ \ 2)\bigr\}$$is a subgroup of $S_3$ with three elements, it must be the only such subgroup of $S_3$.

Comment: The problem was about a subgroup of S6, not S3. Thank you either way.

Comment: Then my guess is that you made an error in the statement of the problem, since $S_6$ has **lots** of subgroups of order $3$.

Comment: I found the problem in a book. I suppose it could be an error. I'll see if I can find some of those subgroups tomorrow, since it does indeed look like there should be more than one of them.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of Lagrange's theorem though :)

Comment: If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are distinct elements of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, then$$\bigl\{\operatorname{id},(a\ \ b\ \ c),(a\ \ c\ \ b)\bigr\}$$is a subgroup of order $3$ of $S_6$.

Comment: It was indeed an error in the book. Thanks for your help! I guess I'll mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.